# Add new Node to the xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add a new node to the xml root to the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Transactions>
  <Transaction>
    <Id>CUST9</Id>
    <SMSFileName>Customer9.txt</SMSFileName>
    <Mobile>918886002141</Mobile>
  </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

which should end up like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Transactions>
  <Transaction>
    <Id>CUST9</Id>
    <SMSFileName>Customer9.txt</SMSFileName>
    <Mobile>918886002141</Mobile>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
    <Id>CUST1</Id>
    <SMSFileName>Customer1.txt</SMSFileName>
    <Mobile>918886002141</Mobile>
  </Transaction>

</Transactions>
```

I have tried the below code but it havent worked

```
  private void RemoveSuccessFullElements(string xmlFile, string transactionNumber)
    {
        FileInfo xmlFileInfo = new FileInfo(xmlFile);
        var rootDirectoryForCurrentFolder = xmlFileInfo.Directory.FullName;
        XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        var archivedXmlFile = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectoryForCurrentFolder).ToList().Where(t => t.ToLower().Contains("archived") && t.ToLower().Contains("xml")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (archivedXmlFile != null)
        {
            FileInfo archivedFileInfo = new FileInfo(archivedXmlFile);

            XmlDocument xDocumentArchived = new XmlDocument();
            xDocumentArchived.Load(archivedXmlFile);
            foreach (XmlNode node in xDocument.SelectNodes("Transactions/Transaction"))
            {
                var transactionIDExistanceResult = isTransactionIdExists(node);
                if (transactionIDExistanceResult)
                {
                    if (node.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText == transactionNumber)
                    {

                        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

                   **I want to add this removed node to new archivedXmlFile file**

                    }
                }

            }
            xDocument.Save(xmlFile);
        }

    }
```

Any clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ImportNode and AppendChild it then: `xDocumentArchived.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xDocumentArchived.ImportNode(node, true);`. And at the end you need to call Save on `xDocumentArchived`: `xDocumentArchived.Save(archivedXmlFile);`.

Comment: Thanks i will try it and let you know